# Extract subset of fields from within a Laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel collection like this (approximating using array syntax; the actual data is a `Collection` of `object`s obtained from an API response, not a local DB):

```php
$rows = [
  [
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Sue',
    'age': 23,
  ],
  [
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Joe',
    'age': 25,
  ],
]
```

I want to extract a subset of the fields:

```php
$subset = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $subset[] = ['name' => $row['name'], 'age' => $row['age']];
}
```

So that I end up with:

```php
$subset = [
  [
    'name': 'Sue',
    'age': 23,
  ],
  [
    'name': 'Joe',
    'age': 25,
  ],
]
```

What [`Collection` method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#available-methods) should I use to achieve that instead of the `for` loop?

I found this suggestion, using a [higher-order message](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#higher-order-messages), which made some kind of sense:

```php
$subset = $rows->map->only(['name', 'age']);
```

but that just gives me a `Collection` of `null` values. Expanding it into a conventional `map` call produced the same effect. I feel like I want some kind of `multipluck`, but I'm not sure what that corresponds to!

### Update

It turns out that I was doing this correctly with the higher-order `map->only` approach. However, while the items in my collection were a kind of `Model`, they were not a subclass or compatible implementation of the *Laravel* `Model` class, and lacked an implementation of the `only` method. The author added the method, and now it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You were close, but you don't chain `map` and `only`, and `only` doesn't seem to work on a Collection of nested `array`s/`object`s.

So, for your case, use `map()` with a Callback:

```
$rows = collect([
  (object)[
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Sue',
    'age' => 23,
  ],
  (object)[
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'Joe',
    'age' => 25,
  ]
]);

$mapped = $rows->map(function ($row) {
  return ['age' => $row->age, 'name' => $row->name];
});

dd($mapped->toArray());
```

Output of that would be:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "age" => 23
    "name" => "Sue"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "age" => 25
    "name" => "Joe"
  ]
]
```

Note: If these are `array`s and not `object`s, then you'd do `$row['age']` and `$row['name']` instead of `$row->age` and `$row->name`. In Laravel, Models are both, and allow either syntax.

References:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-map

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-only

Edit:

Some alternatives. If you have a `Collection` of `Model`s, then you can natively do:

```
$mapped = $rows->map(function ($model) {
  return $model->only(['age', 'name']);
});
```

If you have a `Collection` of `Collection`s, then you can do:

```
$mapped = $rows->map(function ($collection) {
  return $collection->only(['age', 'name']);
});
```

And lastly, if you `array`s or `object`s, you can `collect()` and call `->only()`:

```
$mapped = $rows->map(function ($row) {
  return collect($row)->only(['age', 'name']);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. You can chain `map` and `only`; that's what the higher-order messages allow; they remove the need for a closure. While this syntax is all good, it turned out that my problem was elsewhere.

Comment: Ohh, there's the lightbulb. Apologies; I have never used `map` without a closure; didn't know you could do that. It's actually similar to Ruby/Rails syntax, where you can do things like `.map(&:to_i)` instead of `.map { |s| s.to_i }`. It also totally makes sense that `->map->only(['age', 'name'])` may or may not work, depending if `->only()` was available. Glad you got it working though 